# Pushing new elements into a map of function pointers "inline"?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, function-pointers

I am creating a map of function pointers as shown in the minimal working example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef std::vector<bool > Bar;
typedef bool (*Foo)(Bar b);
typedef std::map<int, Foo > MapOfFunctions;

inline bool f1 (Bar b) { return b[0] && b[1]; }

int main() {
  MapOfFunctions myMap;

  myMap[0] = f1; // works
  //myMap[1] = // Define a function right here, "in line"?!

  if (myMap[0](Bar (2,true) ))
    cout << "it's true" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to know whether it is possible to define new elements (i.e. functions) of the map "inline", i.e. right in the code, without having to first create a separate function elsewhere in the code (`f1` in this example).

**Edit**: the solution should preferably be C++98.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, captureless lambda expressions are convertible to function pointers:

```
myMap[3] = [](Bar) { return false; };
myMap[7] = [](Bar b) -> bool { b.clear(); return b.size(); };
```

Comment: How about a C++98 solution? It seems that this is a C++11 feature. Sorry for not mentioning this requirement in the OP.

Comment: @space_voyager: No, sorry.

Comment: @space_voyager, `boost::function` holding `boost::bind` results or `Boost.Phoenix` lambas.